# Motherboard-CPU compatibility dilemma?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cache

I noticed a discrepancy on Asus motherboard-CPU compatibility page. Where the CPU cache is listed, sometimes it appears as half of the real value or a third of it.

For example this `Athlon IIX3 405e(AD405EHDK32GI), 2.3GHz, 512KB, rev.C2,45W, Socket AM3`  and on CPU-World the cache is triple.

This only happens with some models.Others are accurate. 
Why is this happening? As it is confusing for someone who wants to make sure his board would work with a certain processor.

Answer (score 1):

ASUS referred the cache PER CORE. CPUWorld just shows the full amount of cache present on the CPU. The processor has 3 cores, so the cache is tripled.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. However it does not clarify something.For instance the dual-core Athlon X2 BE-2350 (DD),1M,45W,rev.G1,SocketAM2 CPU appears with 1M cache both un ASUS and cpuworld. So they didn't list them all in the same manner I guess?

Comment: Yeah, they really have to confuse that all..

Comment: I will buy them anyway since people can't come up with a clear answer.So then my questions are: what is the worst case scenario? I guess the PC just wouldn't start. Or maybe it would start and later certain things would not work properly? Or it would do some damage to other components? I don't have a clue. :(

Comment: No need to worry about the cache, core revision or other miscallenous things. Just check if the CPU is present on the ASUS motherboard compatible processor list. If your CPU is listed, just install it and use your pc, there's no other thing to worry about.

Comment: Oh, this is a relief for me.

Comment: That's good to know!